# Flagging posts as off topic for SO

Tags: feature-request, flags

When flagging posts as *Flagging->Closing->Off-Topic->Migration*, there is a very limited set of other sites that it could be for.

For example (and it is just that, no question from):

Questions with the WordPress tag, should belong on wordpress.stackexchange (IMO)

So I ask the following:

*Would it be possible to extend this flag to include a wider variety of other SE sites?*

Comment: Thank you for the flag, I found it very helpful to me, I hope it continues to help others find the answer to this question :)

Comment: It evidently hasn't so far... [37 and counting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/251652?lq=1), not including any deleted in embarrassment.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, agreed, but it could be of use to someone (including myself) :P